# Eclipse fire up

Tags: eclipse

I'm re-installing Eclipse, after I installed Android Studio. To do so, I deleted and re-installed all Java installations. Now I can't start Eclipse even I have jdk and jre installed on my machine. I'm getting this message " A JRE and JDK must be available. 
Any ideas what I suppose to do?

Comment: do you have changed your JDK installation path?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows.

Install the Eclipse according to the system you are using i.e., is it a x64 or x86, and Install the Java  x64 and x86 Accordingly.

[how to know my PC running the 32-bit or 64-bit version of Windows?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows7/find-out-32-or-64-bit)

this should help.